# How can I run implicit animations between Routes?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, riverpod

In my app are multiple pages / routes. Each of the Widgets implementing the pages has a Scaffold at the root of the build method (as is customary in Flutter).
On some routes I want to hide or change certain parts of the UI - for example the leading icon in the `AppBar` is an `AnimatedIcon` that changes between the "open drawer" hamburger and the back arrow.
On some routes I want to animate out the `NavigationBar`, on some routes there is no FAB or there are different actions available in the `AppBar`.

Most of these per-element transitions are realised via `AnimatedSwitcher`s, so for example on each page there is an `AnimatedSwitcher` for the `bottomNavigationBar` parameter of the `Scaffold`, but only for some the `child` of the switcher is a `NavigationBar`, for others it's just `null`, resulting in an animation aslong as Flutter knows that both `AnimatedSwitcher`s are the same.

Now the issue is - how do I actually implement this properly?
Flutter needs to somehow be made aware of there being a continuity between the different pages, because otherwise it will not run the transition animations and instead it'll just hard cut between the layouts.

I've tried (and I think this is still the most promising approach) to give each of the Scaffolds the same key.

```
Router
|_ Route
  |_ Scaffold
    |_ key: myGlobalKey
    |_ appBar: AnimatedSwitcher
      |_ actions:
        |_ AnimatedSwitcher
          |_ Icons
    |_ bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedSwitcher
      |_ BottomNavigationBar
|_ Route
  |_ Scaffold
    |_ key: myGlobalKey
    |_ appBar: AnimatedSwitcher
      |_ actions:
        |_ AnimatedSwitcher
          |_ null
    |_ bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedSwitcher
      |_ null
```

This generally works (animations fluidly continue / start & stop), but breaks down if there are two Scaffolds in the scene, which might happen on some transitions (though I am using `go_router`s `NoTransitionPage`), and especially when using `IndexedStack` for the `NavigationBar`.
As a mitigation I tried watching on a Riverpod provider observing the Navigators current route which would then switch the key as such: `key: isCurrentRoute ? scaffoldKey : null` -- but that still resulted in duplicate keys.

Another approach I tried was lifting the `Scaffold` out of the pages (so that every page is just the content) and then, from inside the pages I would write into a provider the desired *Scaffold* and all of the props on that (but the key) would then be applied to that top level `Scaffold`.
This unfortunately wasn't successful either and ended up just looking as if I had done nothing: each page just appears without any transition running, because Flutter treats everything as being new / throws away all of the State.

It might be still that either approach could work and I just didn't do it correctly -- if so please point it out, I just want to get this working.